# the page contains markup that is not valid

Tags: html

hey i have several forms one of form when i view design it show me error 
"the page contains markup that is not valid when attahed to master page "

aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
     CodeBehind="DownDoc.aspx.cs" Inherits="FYPDMS.DownDoc" Title="Untitled Page" %>
  <asp:Content ID= "Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID =  "ContentPlaceHolder1" 
     runat="server">
       <div id="cssmenuuuu">

   <ul>
      <li class="active">
```

site master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site2.master.cs"    
    Inherits="FYPDMS.Site2" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  
     /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

ERROR IN ASPX PAGE

where is the problem?

Comment: Do you know _anything at all_ about HTML? If not, then stay away from ASP.NET until you do. You have to close those tags!

Comment: you need to close your tags

Comment: @DaiBok i already closed in form i.e </asp:Content> but i still gives me error

Comment: Close the `<div>` tag!

Comment: i already closed but it still show error</asp:Content>

Comment: i dont post whole code of html i done this tags in my form.. but it still shows me error and  i closed all tags

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. The designer isn't imagining this. You have a real problem. Try going into source view and using Format Document (maybe Control-K Control-D)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
     CodeBehind="DownDoc.aspx.cs" Inherits="FYPDMS.DownDoc" Title="Untitled Page" %>
  <asp:Content ID= "Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID =  "ContentPlaceHolder1" 
     runat="server">
       <div id="cssmenuuuu">

        <ul>
          <li class="active"/>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```